# java string split on all non-alphanumeric except apostrophes

Tags: java, regex

So I want to split a string in java on any non-alphanumeric characters.

Currently I have been doing it like this

```
words= Str.split("\\W+");
```

However I want to keep apostrophes("'") in there.  Is there any regular expression to preserve apostrophes but kick the rest of the junk?  Thanks.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
words = Str.split("[^\\w']+");
```

Just add it to the character class. `\W` is equivalent to `[^\w]`, which you can then add `'` to.

Do note, however, that `\w` also actually includes underscores. If you want to split on underscores as well, you should be using `[^a-zA-Z0-9']` instead.

Comment: Sure, but since they were already using `\W`, I chose to preserve that. However, I did add a note about it.

Comment: `a-zA-Z` only works for English chars. A more general approach is `\p{L}`. BTW to reduce confusion you should really escape that backslash.

Comment: How to add new line to the above pattern?

Answer (score 19):

For basic English characters, use

```
words = Str.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9']+");
```

If you want to include English words with special characters (such as *fiancé*) or for languages that use non-English characters, go with

```
words = Str.split("[^\\p{L}0-9']+");
```

Comment: this doesn't work with a string = "&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; a&nbsp; &nbsp; ";

Comment: I meant by "&nbsp;" a space in the string

Comment: @maroodb - Well, for the `split` the "&nbsp;" is a string, not a character, although it is converted into a single character in the HTML output. In this case the regex pattern has to be adjusted accordingly. See https://ideone.com/3RbBj5 for an example of such implementation. I hope this will solve the issue you are facing.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt explain correctly I meant; string = "{there is spaces here} somedata"

Comment: @maroodb - You will need to adjust the regex pattern. If you want to split by additional strings (let's say `one`, `two`, `three`), then the pattern needs to include such strings in it: `Str.split("(one|two|three|[^a-zA-Z0-9'])+")`

Comment: I dont need to split by additional string, can you try this string with your solution please ? https://justpaste.it/4493s

Comment: @maroodb - What exactly you are looking for? Please be more specific what outputs you expect for selected inputs. More exact examples allow me to better understand your needs.

Comment: did you try the given string with your solution ? the regex dont remove leading spaces

Comment: @maroodb - I really don't know what you are missing here: https://ideone.com/U52U9T

Comment: Ah okay, I didn't add this condition if(words[i].length()>0) .. thank you

Comment: @maroodb - That condition was there from the beginning - see my very first reply to your comment. Anyway, I am glad you made it work. Good luck.