# Java String Split On Non-Alphabetic Characters

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I want to split a String into a String array along non-alphabetic characters.  For example:

```
"Here is an ex@mple" => "Here", "is", "an" "ex", "mple"
```

I tried using the [String.split(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method with the regular expression `"(?![\\p{Alpha}])"`. However this splits the string into

```
"Here", "_is", "_an", "_ex", "@ample"
```

(those underscores are to emphasize there is a space). I guess this is because the `?!` regex operator is "zero-width" and is actually splitting on and removing a zero-width character preceding the non-alphabetic characters in the input string.

How can I accomplish removal of the actual non-alpha characters while I split the string? Is there a NON-zero-width negation operator?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332772/java-string-split-on-all-non-alphanumeric-except-apostrophes

Comment: @Thilo That won't work with underscores

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could try **`\P{Alpha}+`**:

```
"Here is an ex@mple".split("\\P{Alpha}+")
```

```
["Here", "is", "an", "ex", "mple"]
```

`\P{Alpha}` matches any non-alphabetic character (as opposed to `\p{Alpha}`, which matches any alphabetic character). `+` indicates that we should split on any continuous string of such characters. For example:

```
"a!@#$%^&*b".split("\\P{Alpha}+")
```

```
["a", "b"]
```

Comment: If I put in "Madam, I'm Adam" it kills the comma and apostrophe, but keeps the space after "Madam," and before "I'm". Is that expected behaviour, or is something wonky with the split? If I add in "|\\s+" it doesn't kill whitespace.

Answer (score 6):

There are already several answers here, but none of them deal well with internationalization issues. And even if it might be assumed from the OP example that it was about "English" letters, it is maybe not the case for visitors coming here from a search...

... so, it worth mentioning that Java supports the [Unicode Technical Standard #18 *"Unicode Regular Expressions"*](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/). Pretty impressing isn't it ? In clear, this is an extension to the classic (latin-centric or event English-centric) regular expressions designated to deal with international characters.

For example, [Java supports the full set of binary properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#ubpc) to check if a character belong to one of the Unicode code point character classes. Especially the [\p{IsAlphabetic}](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#unicode) character class would match any alphabetic character corresponding to a letter in any of the Unicode-supported langages.

Not clear ? Here is an example:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{IsAlphabetic}+");
    //                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //                         any alphabetic character
    //                    (in any Unicode-supported language)

    Matcher m = p.matcher("L'élève あゆみ travaille _bien_");
    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(">" + m.group());
    }
```

Or mostly equivalent using split to break on *non*-alphabetic characters:

```
    for (String s : "L'élève あゆみ travaille bien".split("\\P{IsAlphabetic}+"))
        System.out.println(">" + s);
```

In both cases, the output will properly tokenize words, taking into account French accentuated characters and Japanese hiragana characters -- just like it would do for words spelled using any Unicode-supported language (including the [supplementary multi-lingual plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Supplementary_Multilingual_Plane))

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't

```
"Here is an ex@mple".split("\\S\\w+")
```

work?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, you could iterate over the characters in the string, test if their ASCII values are in the range of lower and upper case letters, and perform your desired 'split' behavior if not.

`char[] chars = str.toCharArray();`  might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Using Square brackets[] in Split Function we can do this,,

SYNTAX : 
   String strArray = text.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");

For Example:
--> for text : "Ready, steady, go!";

The String Array would be,, strArray = [Ready,steady,go];

For Example:
--> for text : "You are the best!!!!!!!!!!!! CodeFighter ever!";

The String Array would be,, strArray = [You,are,the,best,CodeFighter,ever];