# Split String end with special characters - Java

Tags: java, regex, string, split, pattern-matching

I have a string which I want to first split by space, and then separate the words from the special characters.

For Example, let's say the input is:

```
Hi, How are you???
```

I already wrote the logic to split by space here:

```
String input = "Hi, How are you???";
String[] words = input.split("\\\\s+");
```

Now, I want to seperate each word from the special character.

For example: `"Hi,"` to `{"Hi", ","}` and `"you???"` to `{"you", "???"}`

If the string does not end with any special characters, just ignore it.

Can you please help me with the regular expression and code for this in Java?

Comment: Are you tokenizing a string into word and non-word/non-whitespace chunks? Check http://ideone.com/iOC7pS

Comment: Could you please precise the exact output you are looking for?

Comment: Do you need a **regex** or **java** code?

Answer (score 0):

Following regex should help you out:

`(\s+|[^A-Za-z0-9]+)`

This is not a java regex, so you need to add a backspace.

It matches on whitespaces `\s+` and on strings of characters consisting **not** of `A-Za-z0-9`. This is a workaround, since there isn't (or at least I do not know of) a regex for special characters.

You can test this regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/rCzFJt/1).

If you use this regex with the `split` function, it will return the words. Not the special characters and whitespaces it machted on.

**UPDATE**

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13714725/1809463) here on SO, java has`\P{Alpha}+`, which matches any non-alphabetic character. So you could try:

`(\s|\P{Alpha})+`

Answer (score 0):

I want to separate each word from the special character.

For example: "Hi," to {"Hi", ","} and "you???" to {"you", "???"}

regex to achieve above behavior

```
String stringToSearch ="Hi, you???";

Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("[a-z]{0}\\b");
String[] str = p1.split(stringToSearch);
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(str));
```

output:

[Hi, , , you, ???]

Answer (score 0):

@mike is right...we need to split the sentence on special characters, leaving out the words. Here is the code:

```
`public static void main(String[] args) {
    String match = "Hi, How are you???";
    String[] words = match.split("\\P{Alpha}+");
    for(String word: words) {
        System.out.print(word + " ");
    }
}`
```